# undefined method 'devise' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have been looking to get to grips with devise and its workings and have kind of fallen at the first hurdle.  I have looked in a few places but cannot seem to find someone with this error exactly.

So I have created a simple Home controller with an index view and added root 'home#index' and also ensured the default url options are setup in the development.rb file.  I then simply typed:

```
rails generate devise User
```

This created my user.rb file in models with the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Pretty straightforward so far, I have the following Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
gem 'bcrypt'
```

And when I run either rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
/home/jonlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
/home/jonlee/Projects/rails/userauth/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<class:User>'
/home/jonlee/Projects/rails/userauth/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Im at a loss as to why the User model cannot find the 'devise' method when as far as I can see it is definitely there.

I get similar errors with rake routes, rails server and rails console.

For further info I am using ruby 2.1.1 if that helps?

Comment: It seems like you missed one step to install the devise initializer. Did you run `rails generate devise:install` command?

Comment: Also getting this issue when using an "Admin" model - and I've run all the necessary steps...

Comment: I had this problem because executed `rails g devise user` before to `rails g devise:install`

I solved this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65554117/1873466

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add `devise` to your application `Gemfile` and install it by running `bundle install`. After this, you should run the following generator command:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

This generator will install an initializer `your_application/config/initializers/devise.rb`  which consists of all the Devise's configuration options.

You missed the above mentioned step which is why the devise configurations are not set and you receive `undefined method 'devise' for User` error in your model class `User`.

Comment: Don't forget the : in the command. My ebook reader barely made the : visible.

Comment: do a git stash save, before, and a git stash pop afterwards

Answer (score 30):

I ran into a similar issue when I was configuring Devise (Ruby 2.4.1 / Rails 5.1.2). In my case it seems that the following files were not created after I executed: `rails generate devise:install` for the first time.

```
create  config/initializers/devise.rb
create  config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

Steps that I followed:

1) Comment from your MODEL the following:

```
  #devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     #:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

2) Comment from routes.rb:

```
#devise_for :sessions
```

3) Run `rails generate devise:install` again, you should see that some files are created this time. Hope you it works !

4) Uncomment from 1) & 2)

5) Execute: `rake db:migrate`

And at this point it should work. Hope it helps someone !

Answer (score 23):

I have the same issue but with other reason. this can also be problem for somebody. Stop rails server
and then type

```
 rails s
```

to **restart it**

Comment: When you have enough rep, this should be added as a comment to either the original question or the answer that it is improving.

Answer (score 17):

I've run the generator `$ rails generate devise:install` but got the same issue.

Anyway it works to me: Add `extend Devise::Models` to the User models.

Comment: IMO this should be the correct answer -- it doesn't exclude people using Devise not in Rails. It is a common pattern to keep models in a separate gem for services that share the same database.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Kirti's answer of running

```
rails generate devise:install
```

you may want to rename the devise initializer to

```
config/initializers/01_devise.rb
```

because if any other initializer (such as config/initializers/active_admin.rb) runs before devise and touches the ApplicationController, you will get the same error.

And according to 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files
you control the load order of initializers using file naming.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. The fix was to uncomment:

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
```

in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`.

I deliberately commented it out earlier because documentation says: "Supports :active_record (default)".

Comment: In my case with gem `devise_token_auth` I had to add this to `config/devise_token_auth.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Extend Devise::Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

Reference: https://dev.to/risafj/guide-to-devisetokenauth-simple-authentication-in-rails-api-pfj

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this same error crop up when I did:

rails g controller client/timesheets

It turned out that the problem was with the generated helper:

app/helpers/client/timesheet_helper.rb:

```
module Client::TimesheetHelper
end
```

Client is a model that uses Single Table Inheritance off of the User model. Something was getting very mixed up her, what with Client being a Model (class) and a module, and it results in this cryptic error message.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I installed Devise and Mongoid, but forgot to change the orm from active_record to mongoid in config/initializers/devise.rb

Should be:

```
require 'devise/orm/mongoid'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to stop the Spring preloader process:

```
spring stop
```

Now works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because executed `rails g devise user` before to `rails g devise:install`

I solved this, removing line  `devise_for :users` at `config/routes.rb`
and deleting  `db/migrate/xxxxxx_add_devise_to_users.rb`

now run

```
rails g devise:install

rails g devise user
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue as well, solved it by :
Steps:

1. Comment out all references to devise most importantly in the routes.rb and
   user.rb model
2. run `rails g devise:install` and be sure you follow the suggested steps
   in the guide on screen.
3. Go on and uncomment references to devise in routes.rb and user.rb
4. run  `rake db:migrate`
   And you good to go!

Answer (score 0):

comment your app/model/user.rb and also comment devise route in config/routes.rb

```
`rails generate devise:install`
```

then run

```
`rails db:migrate`
```

then uncomment all done before

this method work for me on rails 7.0.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into the same problem.
For your case, you should first of all stop the server, and restart it. This should work out!

For more insight, you should also consier visiting this site; https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue now with a lagacy system. The problem was caused by a commented line (remained there at migration from Rails 4 to 5) in the header of `config/routes.rb`:

```
#V2p0::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
```

The devise initialization script inserted `devise_for` also below the commented line. After removing it the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -4):

### **Comment out:-**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

---

in `user.rb` Model. This worked for me

Comment: That turns off devise functionality.

The answer for me was to restart the rails server after running `rails generate devise:install`