# `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded devise in Gem of my app.When I did `bundle exec rails server -b` 0.0.0.0 in terminal,I got a error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
```

I read other error message of above error it said

```
user.rb:4:in `<class:User>' and user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

were wrong but I don't know why these sentences are wrong(because its part is `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable`)

What should I do to fix this error?

I wrote , in `user.rb` file:

```css
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

in migrate file,

```css
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

In `application_controller.rb` file:

```css
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

in `routes.rb` file:

```css
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users
  get 'pages/index'

  get 'pages/show'

  get 'home/index'

  root 'pages#index'
  get 'pages/show'

  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'

  namespace :connection do
      get '/',action:'index'
    end
end
```

Comment: In your User model can you try `class User < ApplicationRecord` as the first line? And did you also run the install command: `rails generate devise:install`? Also a duplicatie question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148723/undefined-method-devise-for-user

Comment: When I did rails generate devise:install ,I got same error like .rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: thx, ur comment. I changed my wrote in user.rb ActiveRecord::Base into ApplicationRecord, and I did bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0.But I got almost same error like
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)

Comment: @sajan maybe I forgot the command.So I deleted devise in Gem and I did same process, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you run the `rails g devise:install` command before or after you created the User model?

Comment: @KevinEtore Yes,it was after I created the User model.But in that time,I got  `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for User error.

Comment: Check the Devise documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#user-content-getting-started. the `generate devise:install` command should be before you generate the Model. Can you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196258/method-missing-undefined-method-devise-for-user-call-user-connection-to#answer-31292051 and see if this solves the problem?

Comment: @KevinEtore   thx, I deleted devise_for :users and did rake db:rollback.But,I got error 
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:

Comment: @KevinEtore Furthermore,I deleted  
get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'  in user.rb,I got error 
ake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUserdata

NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUserdata

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

So,I cannot do generate devise:install.What should I do?

Comment: Did you try to rollback?

Comment: I did rake db:rollback but I got same error
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUserdata

NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUserdata

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: @KevinEtore What should I do?Is making new app better for me?

Comment: I would suggest that yes. You now know where the mistake is, so it shouldn't take to much time to redesign it.

Comment: @KevinEtore thx, teaching me a lot

Comment: @Rose2017 If you consider that this is answered please close the question or post the answer and mark it as correct, with this you probably would help to somebody in the future with the same issue. Maybe you can post that the issue was the order of the commands for devise :)